# How to install and configure QGIS WEB CLIENT in Windows

Tags: qgis

I have the problem configuring my QGIS web Client. I'm new in QGIS. These are the tool I use:

1. Xampp
2. QGIS Server
3. QGIS Web Client
4. QGIS Desktop

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to describe the complete process you are using and the problem encountered.